# How to ungroup Column groups and covert them into rows using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following table from downloading stock data downloaded for multiple stocks. I used the following code

```
i = ['NTPC.NS', 'GAIL.NS']
stock = yf.download(tickers=i, start='2021-01-11', end='2021-03-10', interval = '5m', group_by = 'tickers')
```

The output dataframe looks like this

[image]

But I want the output to be like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) by first level, then rename index names and convert last level of `MultiIndex` to column by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = stock.stack(level=0).rename_axis(['Datetime','stockname']).reset_index(level=-1)
#if necessary change order of columns
df = df[df.columns.tolist()[1:] + df.columns.tolist()[:1]]
```

Comment: ```ValueError: Length of names must match number of levels in MultiIndex.
```
I am getting this error when I use the first line of the code

Comment: @AnirudhMurali - You are right, so answer was edited.